# How to make sure the incoming voice from Google tts have fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Testing in low network speed, for a proper use of Google tts API from JavaScript, the case is that sometimes it reads and some times it's not, it may read very short text like 'hi', how to make sure the requested audio have load.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title></title>
       <script>
        function playit() {
                var audio = new Audio();
                audio.src = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en&q=Okay i can read but not alwayes';
                //function(){testbeforplaying;}
                audio.play();
        }
      </script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <input type="button" value="say" onclick="playit()"/>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading audio (or video, or images) is an asynchronous operation so you need to listen to tap into the browser's callback mechanism to know when the file is ready for use.

**Update**

Added `type` to the mix, and demo:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/q5wt4/)**

In case of audio (and video) you can listen to the `canplay` event:

```
function playit() {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
        this.play();
    }, false);
    audio.type = 'audio/mpeg';
    audio.src = '...';
}
```

You could also use `canplaythrough` instead of `canplay`.

Optionally do this:

```
function playit() {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.preload = 'auto';
    audio.autoplay = true;
    audio.type = 'audio/mpeg';
    audio.src = '...';
}
```

There seem to be [an issue with Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=281710) though - it cancels flat out:

[image]

Comment: Yes it loads fine for both examples but only in IE10 not Firefox or even Chrome.

Comment: @MuhammedTalha strange.. It seem to have to do with media type. It works in FF when defining the type (`audio.type = 'media/mpeg';`) but it has no effect on Chrome. Could be an issue with Chrome and source url. I updated answer with a fiddle.

Comment: Isee but in Firefox too, and if we try to deal with the API in the server level -i mean PHP- it will work fine and play the mp3 file.

Comment: @MuhammedTalha works in my FF (version 29). Could be issues with both due to the way the link is formatted. PHP would allow you to load the byte stream and read the mime-type directly. Did you try with a different audio source (non-dynamical, ie. an existing mp3 file) just to test the code?

Comment: ok i am looking for using existing source, for Firefox, try to change the text and it will not work again as i have.

Comment: @MuhammedTalha I used one of [my own tracks](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/W9vzF/) (disclaimer: I'm the copyright holder, feel free to use for testing and non-commercial use) with the same code. Plays fine in Chrome/FF. The issue (I added a link in my answer) is known for Chrome, but the same issue could exist for older FF. I believe the reason is that the link is dynamic and Chrome has problems interpreting mime-type from it even when set manually.

Comment: see this example as well it is similar but not same 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242155/is-chrome-and-firefox-does-not-load-the-voice-coming-throught-google-tts-api

Comment: @MuhammedTalha yeah, in the fiddle I encoded the url. I tried with encodeURI* as well but with no success in my attempts. But I'll leave it there as the code works (in itself, unless I missed something very obvious) and the Chromium team need to be the one fixing the url issue. Lets hope they fix it very soon!

Comment: Yes,  see your fiddle thank you for collaboration, however it might be a solution, since both of the browsers can read for the first time, and if you change the text sent it will not, did you notice that!?

Comment: @MuhammedTalha when you mention it I did actually (I removed the last `s`) but I didn't check it out further.. could be some caching issues involved as well (but it seem to work when using the link directly.. strange case).