# Is Chrome and Firefox do not load the change in media source?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, html5-audio

I tried this code in IE10 it works fine but not in Chrome or Firefox, if we made a call directly for the Google tts API URL in the Chrome or Firefox browser, it works first time only and then it will only load the same text from the script, if any change for the submitted text has happened from the script, no reading will occur. see the example below please!

```
 <head>
    <script>
      // audio= new Audio();
        function playit() {
                var toread=document.getElementById('texttoread').value;
                 var audio = new Audio();
                audio.src = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?rel=noreferrer&ie=UTF-8&tl=en&q='+toread;
          //      audio.load();
                audio.play();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="texttoread"
        type="text" 
        value="say" 
    />
    <input 
        type="button" 
        value="say hi" 
        onclick="playit()"
    />

</body>
```

If any one can tell, that the incoming media will be saved to some sort of file or cashed, and this data somehow not directly rewritable again, what i believe is must be some kind of reset or clear.

Comment: See encodeURIComponent.

Comment: yes but no response as well

Comment: @ALMEK Where did you get this code, exactly?  Everything I'm reading is suggesting that the translate API is not free, but something you pay for.

Comment: @ALMEK Ya.. this isn't free.  Its a hack you found on a non-official blog; google has means of preventing access to their paid service, which is why it doesn't work.  If you want access to the service, you have to pay for it and then use the given API key.

Comment: @Daedalus, Like how much.

Comment: @ALMEK https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing